# Postdoc application under review for three months?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job

I applied for a postdoctoral position at a university in the USA at the end of April, and it has been under review until now (late July). I reached out to the university, and they responded that if I were rejected, I would be notified. However, I noticed that the position has disappeared from the university career page. I am relatively new to academia and unsure what might have happened (before asking my supervisor). If anyone has any insights or information, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say with any certainty. They might have removed it knowing they would be hiring from among current applicants. It is possible, however, that someone else has gotten an offer and they are waiting on their decision. You will hear from them eventually.

They are unlikely to tell you whether you are the first choice or not, but it seems a bit (a bit) unlikely that you are. There might be internal discussions (arguments?) about offers.

Patience is advised. But there is no reason not to talk it over with your supervisor. I also suggest not giving up on other explorations open to you.